# setViewControllers equivalent in watchOS 2 to set the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, watchos-2

In iOS, if you want to manipulate a UINavigationController (e.g. pop two view controllers, then push one), you can do so by using [setViewControllers(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:). Is there an equivalent method in watchOS 2?

If not, how can I pop two interface controllers then push a third interface controller?